# Is telnet/telnet-server a remote shell?

Tags: shell, remote, telnet

It is always said to use Secure Shell (SSH) instead of Telnet or rsh/rcp/rlogin, for security reason.

SSH and rsh are both remote shells. I wonder if telnet is also **a remote shell**? If yes, why is it a remote shell, or how shall I understand that it is a remote shell?

[The definition of a remote shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Shell) is

> The remote shell (rsh) is a command line computer program that can execute shell commands as another user, and on another computer across a computer network.

I looked up how telnet is used. [What I found was that](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/utelnet.htm) a telnet client can connects to a telnet server (when connecting to the telnet port) or another process (when connecting to a port other than the telnet port), **which is already running on a server machine**. It seems to me that telnet can't **execute i.e. launch a shell command on a server machine**, which is part of the definition of a remote shell.

When I looked for alternatives to telnet which is based on UDP, [some mentioned that `netcat` and `nc` are such alternative programs](https://serverfault.com/questions/395342/telnet-counterpart-for-udp). If I am correct, `netcat` and `nc` are both used to **connect to a process already running on a machine**, but not to **execute i.e. launch a process on a machine**. Does it also suggest that telnet is used to **connect to a process already running on a machine**, but not to **execute i.e. launch a process on a machine**?

If it is true that telnet is used to **connect to a process already running on a machine**, but not to **execute i.e. launch a process on a machine**, why is it compared to SSH, given that SSH and telnet are doing different things?

Thanks.

p.s.

I just realized [the Wikipedia article for remote shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Shell) seems to be for a particular program `rsh` and `rshd`.

What I mean by a "**remote shell**" in my post is a type of programs or protocols that can be used to connect to a remote machine, launch a shell on the remote, and launch commands or programs in the shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`telnet` was the traditional way to get a remote shell on a networked unix machine.  `rsh` was the other.  `ssh` is a relative newcomer in comparison.

`telnet` typically talks to a remote telnet *daemon* (or "server" process).  At that point you authenticate with a username and password to login and then you get a shell.  So, yes, it's a method of getting a remote shell.

The `telnet` client can also be used for other connections by specifying another port (eg `telnet host 80` will talk to the web server); this isn't a remote shell.  It's the combination of `telnet` talking to `telnetd` and authenticating that gives the remote shell.

`telnet` is not recommended for remote shell because the username and password are typically passed over the network in plain text; a network sniffer or "man in the middle" attack can steal your password.  Not good!  `ssh` encrypts the traffic to help prevent this.

Example of telnet giving a remote shell:

```
% telnet server.name
Trying 192.168.100.100...
Connected to server.name
Escape character is '^]'.

NetBSD/i386 (server.name) (pts/51)

login: fred
Password:
Last login: Fri Jun 24 21:45:29 2016 from 192.168.1.1 on pts/23

No mail.

$ whoami
fred

$ pwd
/home/fred

$ logout
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: thanks. 1. for your second paragraph, can you give commands that can give a remote shell, so that I can execute some command in the remote shell afterwars, just like what I can do after logging in via ssh? 2. for your third paragraph, when a telnet client connects to a port which is different from the telnet server's port, you mentioned it is not a remote shell. Then does the following sentence " It's the combination of telnet talking to telnetd and authenticating that gives the remote shell" mean that it gives a remote shell?

Comment: Example of `telnet` to get a remote shell added.  This is only a remote shell because it talks to `telnetd` and lets you login and get a command shell.

Comment: Thanks. That addresses the first part in my previous comment, and there is part 2 about the third paragraph in your post.

Comment: `telnet server 80` talks to the web server.  This isn't `telnetd` and so doesn't give a remote shell.  It'd allow you to pretend to be a dumb web client.  Remeber, it's the _server_ that grants the shell and not the client.  telnetd, rlogind, sshd...  So if you talk to `httpd` then you won't get a shell.